# How can i use class of variables in windows forms application and user control dll file?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dll

In the windows forms project i created a new class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FTP_ProgressBar
{
    class FtpConfig
    {
        public static string txtHost;
        public static string txtUsername;
        public static string txtPassword;
        public static string txtDir;
        public static string txtUploadFile;
        public static string txtPort;
        public static System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox chkPassive;
        public static FtpSettings f;
    }
}
```

And in form1 i have a click button where i'm calling a method with the settings:

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            FtpSettings();
        }
```

Then:

```
private void FtpSettings()
        {
            if (this.ftpProgress1.IsBusy)
            {
                this.ftpProgress1.CancelAsync();
                this.btnUpload.Text = "Upload";
            }
            else
            {
                FtpConfig.txtHost = this.txtHost.Text;
                FtpConfig.txtUsername = this.txtUsername.Text;
                FtpConfig.txtPassword = this.txtPassword.Text;
                FtpConfig.txtDir = this.txtDir.Text;
                FtpConfig.txtUploadFile = this.txtUploadFile.Text;
                FtpConfig.txtPort = this.txtPort.Text;
                FtpConfig.chkPassive = this.chkPassive;

                this.toolStripProgressBar1.Visible = true;
                this.ftpProgress1.RunWorkerAsync(FtpConfig.f);
                this.btnUpload.Text = "Cancel";
            }
        }
```

The problem is that i have in my form1 designer a control i dragged over after adding dll file to the toolbox the control have like windows explorer with treeView1 and listView1:

[image: Explorer Window]

The explorer windows is the left one with the C node tree expanded.

The problem is i need somehow to call/use the FtpSettings() method in form1 with the dll library class in this event:

```
void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ClickedItem.Text == "Upload")
            {
                List<String> selected = new List<String>();
                string dir = treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath;
                dir = dir + "\\";
                foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.SelectedItems)
                {
                    string g = Path.Combine(dir, lvi.Text);
                    selected.Add(g);
                }

                AllFiles = selected.ToArray();
                FilesFromExplorerOrManual = false;
                Bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
```

So after added the control dll file to my form1 toolbox dragged it to the form1 designer i need to call the FtpSettings method each time i click on Upload:

```
if (e.ClickedItem.Text == "Upload")
```

After this line: FtpSettings();

But first i don't have access to the event after dragging it to the form1 designer.
Second maybe i will need to call the FtpSettings() in other events in this dll.

I tried after dragging it in form1 designer then i have a variable: explorerTree1 so i tried to do in form1 constructor:

```
explorerTree1.MouseUp += explorerTree1_MouseUp;
```

Then:

```
void explorerTree1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                FtpSettings();
            }
        }
```

I used a breakpoint but it never stop/get to this event. And it also not the same event in the dll file that i need to get to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be watching Drag and Drop events, instead. Please review [the docs from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/9zeew0h4(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx) as the subject is quite extensive.